# How to password protect SQLite Database using System.Data.SQlite.EF6

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using EF6 to work with Sqlite database, Now I would like to password protect my local Sqlite database. I did googling but most of the links are using **"Entity Framework core"** or using **"Ado .net"**.
Anyone has sample or any hint how I will achieve this using EF6.  I am using following packages:

[image]

Database extension: .db

Answer (score 0):

The legacy CryptoAPI database encryption codec is disabled by default in all release binaries. You will have to build the binaries yourself, enabling the encryption codec at compile-time. Or you can obtain a license for the [SEE extension](https://sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki) to SQLite.